# Email verification flow breaks RESTful approach

Tags: rest, email-verification

Current paradigm of email verification:

1. Send an email to the user containing a link with a token.
2. User opens the email and clicks on the link.
3. User resource updated with the new verified email.

In step 2, a GET request is being performed to get the resource, for example

```
GET /email-verification/{token}
```

Since the resource is being updated behind the scenes, doesn't it break the RESTful approach ?

Is this the common approach ?

Doing POST/PATCH requests from email would require a form and i'm not sure email clients support it.

Comment: I believe the link in the email should open a static web page which will call your REST API with the PUT method (idempotent) either from the controller generating this page in a multi-page application, or from an AJAX call in a single-page application. A GET method shouldn't modify any data on your server (idempotent and safe (only retrieving data)).